# Grand total on last page only and subtotals on each page - RDLC

Tags: c#, .net, rdlc

I have a table(as I have a fixed number of columns and dynamic number of rows) with 5 columns where the result set can be spread across multiple pages.
I want each page to have subtotal of one of the columns(call it amount) and on the last page I need to print grand total on this column as well(i.e. on last page there will be 2 totals for that column).

I'm trying to achieve this by adding 2 totals to the table(in the body) with no success.

Also tried adding just 1 total to the table(body) and than the grand total in the footer - also with no success.

What is the recommended way of doing that? I'm sure its a very common scenario.

Comment: Why is the question being down voted? please at least leave a comment so I'll be able to learn for next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
Add a parent group to the first group and limit the number of rows per page using the following expression

`=CEILING(RowNumber(Nothing)/13)` (where 13 is the number of rows per page)

add a footer to this group that will calculate your total per page(subtotal) using the sum function on one of the columns from the child group.

To achieve the grand total just add a total row to your table your tablix object that will only be presented in the last page.